# How can i write data that is coming from Firebase to store quickly?

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux

Firstly, I'm working with React Native. I'm getting a data from Firebase and want to write to store (by Redux) quickly. But It doesn't work. You can find my all of codes below:

**Function:**

```
async getTumData (uid) {

    const {selectedGroupDetail, getSelectedGroupDetail} = this.props;
    var yeniGrupDetayi = {};
    await firebase.database().ref("/groups/"+uid).once('value').then(
      function(snapshot){
        yeniGrupDetayi = {...snapshot.val(), uid: uid};
      }).catch(e => console.log(e.message));

      console.log("FONKSIYON ICERISINDEKI ITEM ==>", yeniGrupDetayi);
      this.props.getSelectedGroupDetail(yeniGrupDetayi);
      console.log("ACTION'DAN GELEN ITEM ===>", selectedGroupDetail);

  }
```

**Action:**

```
export const getSelectedGroupDetail = (yeniGrupDetayi) => {
  return {
    type: GET_SELECTED_GROUP_DETAIL,
    payload: yeniGrupDetayi
  }
};
```

**Reducer:**

```
case GET_SELECTED_GROUP_DETAIL:
      return { ...state, selectedGroupDetail: action.payload}
```

**Çıktı:**

```
FONKSIYON ICERISINDEKI ITEM ==> {admin: {…}, groupDescription: "Yaygın inancın tersine, Lorem Ipsum rastgele sözcü…erini incelediğinde kesin bir kaynağa ulaşmıştır.", groupName: "İnsan Kaynakları", groupProfilePic: "", members: {…}, …}

ACTION'DAN GELEN ITEM ===> {}
```

There is a FlatList in my page and I defined a button in renderItem of FlatList. When i click to this button, `getTumData()` function is working.

When i click to this button first time, `selectedGroupDetail` is `null`. Second time, it shows previous data.

How can i write a data to Store quickly and fast?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is:
 - You're using both async/await, and then/catch in your code.
 - you're calling getSelectedGroupDetail before your async code resolves.

**Fast Solution**

```
getTumData =  (uid) => {

    const {selectedGroupDetail, getSelectedGroupDetail} = this.props;
    var yeniGrupDetayi = {};
    firebase.database().ref("/groups/"+uid).once('value').then(
     (snapshot) => {
        yeniGrupDetayi = {...snapshot.val(), uid: uid};
        this.props.getSelectedGroupDetail(yeniGrupDetayi);
      }).catch(e => console.log(e.message));   
  };
```

**Better Solution:**

1st: use Redux-Thunk middleware.
2nd: Move your Async code into your action creator: I mean this

```
async getTumData (uid) {

    const {selectedGroupDetail, getSelectedGroupDetail} = this.props;
    var yeniGrupDetayi = {};
    await firebase.database().ref("/groups/"+uid).once('value').then(
      function(snapshot){
        yeniGrupDetayi = {...snapshot.val(), uid: uid};
      }).catch(e => console.log(e.message));

      console.log("FONKSIYON ICERISINDEKI ITEM ==>", yeniGrupDetayi);
      this.props.getSelectedGroupDetail(yeniGrupDetayi);
      console.log("ACTION'DAN GELEN ITEM ===>", selectedGroupDetail);

  }
```

3rd: Your reducer should have another piece of data as an indicator for the time-gap before your selectedGroupDetail resolves:

```
// reducer initial state:
const INITIAL_STATE = { error: '', loading: false, selectedGroupDetail: null }
```

4th: Inside your action creator, you should dispatch 3 actions:
ACTION_NAME_START // This should should only set loading to true in your reducer.
ACTION_NAME_SUCCESS // set loading to false, and selectedGroupDetail to the new collection retured
ACTION_NAME_FAIL // in case op failed set error

5th: Your React component, should display a loading indicator (spinner or somthing), and maybe disable FlatList button during the loading state.

```
// Action creator
export const myAction = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: ACTION_NAME_START });
  firebase.database().ref("/groups/"+uid).once('value').then(
  function(snapshot){
    yeniGrupDetayi = {...snapshot.val(), uid: uid};
    dispatch({ type: ACTION_NAME_SUCCESS, payload: yeniGrupDetayi  });

  }).catch(e => {
  dispatch({ type: ACTION_NAME_FAIL, payload: e.message });
});

};


// Reducer
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  loading: false,
  error: '',
  data: null,
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ACTION_NAME_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: '',
        loading: true,
        data: null,
      };

    case ACTION_NAME_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: '',
        loading: false,
        data: payload,
      };

    case ACTION_NAME_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false,
        data: null,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
``try {
    const payload = await myAsyncFunc();
    dispatch({ type: ACTION_NAME_SUCCESS, payload });
  }`` 
this myAsyncFunc is getTumData () ? am i right?

Comment: yes true, and another thing, we either use async-await || .then.catch syntax for async operations ... and the thing is you're using both in your syntax ...

Comment: Finally, can i fix my function (in component, not Action creator) like ``getTumData (uid) { this.props.myAction(uid); }`` ?

Comment: Thanks Hend, I tried to Fast Solution then i have got an error message ``Cannot read property 'getSelectedGroupDetail' of undefined``. I connected this redux function to my component. Why prop is not reading?

Comment: convert your getTumData function into an arrow function to get 'this' context ... check out the edit

Comment: Hend, I have tried "Fast Solution" but it didn't change anything. I will try other one.

Comment: fast solution should work ... post the error you got, maybe i could help 
( if  it's Cannot read property 'getSelectedGroupDetail' of undefined - please revise my answer, you should convert all anonymous functions into arrow functions in order to get 'this' context ... plz take a look at the code again)

Comment: I have solved my problem with your "Better Solution". Thank you so much for your effort. Everything is ok but i want to ask a little question. I added "console.log(state)" in the beginning of the Reducer code. When i click to button, first ACTION_NAME_START was running (data is null), then ACTION_NAME_SUCCESS was running (data is NOT null) but finally when i look at the console, i was seeing DATA is null. I think ACTION_NAME_START is running after ACTION_NAME_SUCCESS. Is that possible ?