# App restarts after fetching data through Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to fetch user data from Firebase to app scene before it is rendered. After fetching the data through action and after dispatch is called from reducer, scene doesn't show up. Instead the app restarts. It's not a crash, because I can see component's logs in console which are showed only when the app starts).

I'm new to React Native and Redux, but this behaviour doesn't makes sense to me.

PlaceDetail.js - component where data should fetch

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ParallaxScrollView from 'react-native-parallax-scroll-view';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import { AirbnbRating } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { ButtonSmall, OneLineDetail, PlaceDescription, Rating } from './common';
import { addRatingToPlace, userPlaceDataFetch } from '../actions';

...

class PlaceDetail extends Component {
    state = { showModal: false };

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.userPlaceDataFetch(this.props.place.uid); // calling an action
    }

    onArrowPress() {
        Actions.pop();
    }

    onVisitButtonPress() {
        this.setState({ showModal: true });
    }

    ratingComplete(pUID, value) {
        this.props.addRatingToPlace(value, pUID);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={containerStyle}>
                <Modal 
                    isVisible={this.state.showModal}
                    onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}    
                    onSwipeComplete={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}
                    swipeDirection="left"
                >
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Text style={modalTitleStyle}>HODNOTENIE</Text>
                        <AirbnbRating
                            count={5}
                            reviews={['Slabé', 'Ujde', 'V pohode', 'Super', 'Vynikajúce']}
                            defaultRating={userDataDetail.rate}
                            size={20}
                            showRating
                            onFinishRating={this.ratingComplete.bind(this, uid)}
                        />
                    </View>
                </Modal>

...

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const userDataDetail = state.userData;

    return { userDataDetail };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addRatingToPlace, userPlaceDataFetch })(PlaceDetail);
```

UserDataActions.js

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/auth';
import '@firebase/database';
import { USER_PLACE_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS } from './types';

export const userPlaceDataFetch = (currentPlaceUID) => {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.database().ref(`users/${currentUser.uid}/ratings/${currentPlaceUID}`)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
                console.log('snapshot.val:', snapshot.val());
                dispatch({ type: USER_PLACE_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
            });
    };
};
```

UserDataReducer.js

```
import { USER_PLACE_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    showModal: false,
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_PLACE_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer';
import ProfileReducer from './ProfileReducer';
import ListReducer from './ListReducer';
import MapReducer from './MapReducer';
import DetailReducer from './DetailReducer';
import UserDataReducer from './UserDataReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    auth: AuthReducer,
    prof: ProfileReducer,
    places: ListReducer,
    maps: MapReducer,
    detail: DetailReducer,
    userData: UserDataReducer
});
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
//import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import Firebase from './Firebase';
import Router from './Router';
import reducers from './reducers';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))}>
                <Router />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Router - to see how my scenes/components are organized

```
<Router>
                <Scene key="root">
                    <Scene key="isLogged" hideNavBar initial>
                        <Scene key="splash" component={Splash} hideNavBar />
                    </Scene>
                    <Scene key="auth" hideNavBar>
                        <Scene key="login" component={LoginForm} hideNavBar />
                    </Scene>
                    <Scene 
                        key="main" 
                        tabs
                        tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#10172C' }} 
                        hideNavBar
                    >
                        <Scene 
                            key="list" 
                            component={ListOfPlaces} 
                            icon={iconList}
                            title="Zoznam miest" 
                            initial
                            hideNavBar 
                            dataPlaces={this.props.places}
                        />
                        <Scene 
                            key="map" 
                            component={MapOfPlaces} 
                            icon={iconMap}
                            title="Mapa" 
                            hideNavBar
                            dataPlaces={this.props.places}
                        />
                        <Scene 
                            key="profile" 
                            component={Profile}
                            icon={iconUser}
                            title="Profil"
                            hideNavBar
                        />
                    </Scene>
                    <Scene 
                        key="place"
                        component={PlaceDetail}
                        hideNavBar
                    />
                </Scene>
            </Router>
```

Comment: where do you consume `PLACES_FETCH_SUCCESS ` action in your reducer ?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, that's wrong file, hold up. I'll fix it.

Comment: check out this answer ... for better handling of async actions in redux
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204422/how-can-i-write-data-that-is-coming-from-firebase-to-store-quickly/55204557#55204557

Comment: Thank You, but this also doesn't work. Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    rate: null, // init your relevant state fields here , or leave it empty
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_PLACE_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, ...action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but this doesn't work. Still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on while making POST requests because it was updating a JSON file in project directory and I had 'Live Reload' setting on app enabled. If you have enabled this setting the app will reload on every file update. Maybe you have this issue.

Comment: If You mean "Live Reload" in Dev Settings in emulator, it's disabled and also i don't have any JSON file in my project, but Thank You for your opinion.